# Conversion into standard pyhton date and time format isn't working correctly

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

This is the initial code: https://pastebin.com/WGwFsD83

```
Time    Value
2020-01-06T21:30:00 0
2020-01-06T21:45:00 1
2020-01-07T15:30:00 2.55
2020-01-07T15:45:00 13.1
2020-01-07T16:00:00 2.88
2020-01-07T16:15:00 5
2020-01-07T16:30:00 -2.3
2020-01-07T16:45:00 -4.8
2020-01-07T17:00:00 6.3
2020-01-07T17:15:00 1.2
2020-01-07T17:30:00 0
```

[[screenshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywapg.jpg)

As you can see, there's a time and value column. In order to plot this time series, I'd need to convert the time format into the python standard time format.

I tried to do it this way:

```
df['datespython'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
```

The problem is that the filetype is not 'datetime64' but 'object' instead. I assumed to_datetime should do such a filetype conversion but apparently I did something wrong.

How can I fix this?

BTW: If I want to create a new column that tells me the week of said observation, i.e. 1 if it's in the first week of the year, could I use this command?

```
df['week'] = df['datespython'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

Comment: please post the data as a text within the question

Comment: @Naveed I posted it now. I'm sorry it looks supper creppy... it's best to copy it from the pastebin website.

Comment: cannot reproduce. your example data converts just fine to datetime64[ns] type.